# Rename container for archived artifacts

Tags: jenkins

We use Jenkins ver. 1.617 for nightly builds. To archive the build results, the post-build-action "archive artifacts" is activated. This works well and Jenkins creates a ZIP-file named *archive.zip* with following structure.

```
archive.zip
|
+--archive
   |
   +--out
      |
      |--*.elf
      |--*.map
      +--*.hex
```

I'd like to replace every *archive* with *Project_Build#* (Build# stands for the current build number). How can I configure Jenkins to do so?

Comment: 7 years later and it seems like there is still no good way to do this :/

Answer (score -1):

You can simply create a needed archive during the job, i.e. if running a shell script with Jenkins - zip all files to an archive called

```
Projekt_Build${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

The build number variable is accessible in shell environment. The simply add the path to the artifact in Jenkins "Archive build artifacts" post-build-action:

```
/path/to/file/Projekt_build${BUILD_NUMBER}
```